# SQL Server remove part of string between characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, charindex

I have emails that look like this:

```
john.doe.946a9979-2951-4852-9e79-ad03eb0c1e5d@gmail.com
```

I am trying to get this output:

```
john.doe@gmail.com
```

I have this so far.... it's close.

```
SELECT 
    Caller = REPLACE(Caller, 
                 SUBSTRING(Caller, 
                    CHARINDEX('.', Caller), 
                       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('@', Caller, CHARINDEX('.', Caller)) > 1 THEN
                           CHARINDEX('@', Caller, CHARINDEX('.', Caller)) - CHARINDEX('.', Caller)
                       ELSE
                          LEN(Caller)
                END  ) , '')
FROM 
    some.table
```

Comment: you need to provide some info about your data, specifically the patterns. Give more than 1 example of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  I suspect the string you want to remove is fixed in length.  So how about:

```
select stuff(caller, charindex('@',caller ) - 37, 37, '')
```

Comment: I tested this and it just returns null values... thanks for your input...

Comment: @user3714526 Gordon just had a typo.  try this one again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler method using `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, and `CHARINDEX()` functions

```
DECLARE @Caller VARCHAR(MAX) = 'john.doe.946a9979-2951-4852-9e79-ad03eb0c1e5d@gmail.com'

SELECT 
    LEFT(@Caller, CHARINDEX('.', @Caller, CHARINDEX('.', @Caller) + 1) - 1) + RIGHT(@Caller, LEN(@Caller) - CHARINDEX('@', @Caller) + 1) Email
```

The left side will get all the characters until the second dot, and the right side will get the characters from @ sign to the end of characters.

Comment: this works great.. I added a little piece to catch length errors.. .
case
when CHARINDEX('@', Caller, CHARINDEX('.', Caller)) > 1 then
    LEFT(Caller, CHARINDEX('.', Caller, CHARINDEX('.', Caller) + 1) - 1) + RIGHT(Caller, LEN(Caller) - CHARINDEX('@', Caller) + 1)
 else Caller
 end test

Comment: @user3714526 glad you found your solution, I can see from your code that the sample doesn't cover all different cases that you have on Caller column, I suggest you review the results, and try to cover them all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SS 2016 or later, you can use R code to do it - granted I don't know about speed on larger data so be wary if its a production environment.  Also be warned Regexp isn't my strongest area so you may want to check that portion.

```
DECLARE @dummyScript NVARCHAR(1000)  = '
SELECT * FROM 
(VALUES (''john.doe.946a9979-2951-4852-9e79-ad03eb0c1e5d@gmail.com''),  
       (''jane whoever 1234453-534343@yahoo.com'') ) t (Email)
'


DECLARE @myRcode NVARCHAR(600)
SET @myRcode = 'OutputDataset <- data.frame(Email_Cleaned = gsub("[0-9]+.+@", "@", InputDataSet$Email))  '


DECLARE @CleanedTable TABLE (Email_Cleaned VARCHAR(500))

INSERT INTO @CleanedTable
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
,@script = @myRcode
,@input_data_1 = @dummyScript
,@input_data_1_name = N'InputDataSet'
,@output_data_1_name = N'OutputDataset'



SELECT * FROM @CleanedTable
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like below

```
    SELECT 
      REPLACE(CALLER,
      Substring(CALLER, 
        PATINDEX('.[0-9]%@', CALLER),
     PATINDEX('@', CALLER  ) )

          ,'@')

     From Table
```

Comment: thanks for your response... I am using sql server....  'REGEXP_REPLACE' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: can you check it now

Comment: Hi Himanshu.. unfortunately, this didn't work .. thanks for trying.

Comment: what is the o/p though

Comment: this is the input: 
   john.doe.946a9979-2951-4852-9e79-ad03eb0c1e5d@gmail.com
this is the needed output: john.doe@gmail.com
this is the output from your code: john.doe.946a9979-2951-4852-9e79-ad03eb0c1e5d@gmail.com
thanks